# Is there an equivalent in Python for TypeScript's Indexed Access Types?

Tags: python, typescript, mypy, typing, pyright

I am currently working with Python and want to know if I can use [Indexed Access Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html). I have a situation where I need to pass two Generic parameters, `A` and `B`, to a class. However, the parameter `B` is always a subtype of `A[item_types]`.

If 'Indexed Access Types' were possible in Python, then I could directly refer to a property type of `A`, eliminating the need to explicitly pass `B`. Here is a snippet of my current code:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, TypedDict


class FieldType(TypedDict):
    pass


class FieldOne(FieldType):
    pass


class FieldTwo(FieldType):
    pass


class MainType(TypedDict):
    item_types: FieldType


class MainOne(MainType):
    item_types: FieldOne


class MainTwo(MainType):
    item_types: FieldTwo


A = TypeVar("A", bound=MainType)
B = TypeVar("B", bound=FieldType)


class Service(Generic[A, B]):
    def __init__(self, main_collection: MongoDBCollection):
        self.main_collection = main_collection

    def get_main(self, document_id: str) -> A:
        return self.main_collection.find_one({'arg': arg})

    def get_field(self, document_id: str) -> B: # B could be A[item_types]
        main = self.get_main(arg)
        return main["item_types"]

service = Service[MainOne, FieldOne]
```

Any assistance or guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, could you update `Service` with an `__init__` method that indicates how `get_main` and `get_field` can return values of type `A` and type `B`, respectively? Second, I think you can make `MainType` itself generic rather than defining explicit subclasses with fixed types for `item_types`.

Comment: I updated the questions. I cannot use Generics with TypedDict :(

Comment: What is `Collection`? For `self.main_collection.find_one` to have a static return type of `A`, I would think `Collection` itself needs to be generic.

Comment: (None of which relates directly to indexed types, which I do not think Python supports in the sense that TypeScript does. But it's not clear yet that your use case *requires* indexed types.)

Comment: `Collection` returns with a mongodb `MainType` document which in my example could be `MainOne` or `MainTwo`. Hence `get_field` returns with `MainOne[item_types] => FieldOne` or `MainTwo[item_types] => FieldTwo`.
I don't know how to annotate `Service` class in that way that I pass only the `MainType` covariant then it knows what is `.get_field` type without passing `FieldType`.

Comment: What is the static type of `arg`? That's the only thing that `find_one` could use to *statically*  indicate that it will return a value of type `A`. (Unless `MongoDBCollection` itself is generic and `A` can be inferred from the specific value used to instantiate `Service`.)

Comment: I updated the questions. `arg` is the same type of param for both of the methods -> `document_id: str`. I cannot refactor the methods as they have some logic inside so my example mainly represents the method signatures/typings.

Comment: Ok, there appears to be no static information available to inform the type checker what `get_main` will return, so there's no way to enforce that it returns somethign of type `A`.